# MDX error in calculated MEASURES

Tags: mdx

I have this MDX query and I want to run in sql MDX:

```
WITH  

MEMBER [Measures].[NMESACT1] AS ([Measures].[ValorBase],[BSC Fact].[Periodo].&[+CStr(2018)+01])  
MEMBER [Measures].[NMESACT2] AS ([Measures].[ValorBase],[BSC Fact].[Periodo].&[+CStr(2018)+02]) 
MEMBER [Measures].[NMESACT3] AS ([Measures].[ValorBase],[BSC Fact].[Periodo].&[+CStr(2018)+03])
MEMBER [Measures].[NMESACT4] AS ([Measures].[ValorBase],[BSC Fact].[Periodo].&[+CStr(2018)+04])
MEMBER [Measures].[NMESACT5] AS ([Measures].[ValorBase],[BSC Fact].[Periodo].&[+CStr(2018)+05])  
MEMBER [Measures].[NMESACT6] AS ([Measures].[ValorBase],[BSC Fact].[Periodo].&[+CStr(2018)+06])  
MEMBER [Measures].[NMESACT7] AS ([Measures].[ValorBase],[BSC Fact].[Periodo].&[+CStr(2018)+07])  
MEMBER [Measures].[NMESACT8] AS ([Measures].[ValorBase],[BSC Fact].[Periodo].&[+CStr(2018)+08])  
MEMBER [Measures].[NMESACT9] AS ([Measures].[ValorBase],[BSC Fact].[Periodo].&[+CStr(2018)+09])  
MEMBER [Measures].[NMESACT10] AS ([Measures].[ValorBase],[BSC Fact].[Periodo].&[+CStr(2018)+10])  
MEMBER [Measures].[NMESACT11] AS ([Measures].[ValorBase],[BSC Fact].[Periodo].&[+CStr(2018)+11]) 
MEMBER [Measures].[NMESACT12] AS ([Measures].[ValorBase],[BSC Fact].[Periodo].&[+CStr(2018)+12])
```

But I always get

> Query (156, 44) Parser: The syntax for ',' is incorrect. (WITH 
>   MEMBER [Measures].[NMESACT1] AS ([Measures].[ValorBase],[BSC Fact].[Periodo].&[+CStr(2018)+01]) etc...

What am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: Greg has supplied the answer below? Basically whenever feeding parameters into MDX you need to use either of the functions `StrToMember` or `StrToSet`

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would just build the dynamic query in whatever tool is executing the query. This approach should perform best as the `StrToMember` function used below will slow down the query.

```
MEMBER [Measures].[NMESACT1] AS ([Measures].[ValorBase],[BSC Fact].[Periodo].&[201801])
```

But if for some reason it needs to be a static query with a @Yr parameter where you pass in "2018" you could do:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[NMESACT1] AS ([Measures].[ValorBase],StrToMember("[BSC Fact].[Periodo].&["+CStr(@Yr)+"01]",CONSTRAINED))
```

But if you want your query to work without parameters and without the client tool building the query, then the following should work:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[NMESACT1] AS ([Measures].[ValorBase],StrToMember("[BSC Fact].[Periodo].&["+CStr(2018)+"01]",CONSTRAINED))
```